# What are the issues with having a long open connection to a web server from a device connected via wifi?

Tags: iphone, security, timeout, connection

I am aware of timeout settings for certain executions over the internet.

My iphone application is downloading videos over the internet via a wifi router connection.

I've heard that a connection like this shouldn't be open for more than 240secs? Is this true?

What dangers/security threats/issues/etc will I encounter the more I increase the timeout? Why do internet connections have a timeout at all?

For instance, if I increase the timeout to 10 or 20 **minutes** then is this bad practice? Bearing in mind this isn't a secure connection or anything, its just a normal connect - download data style connection.

For anyone with iphone experience it is a NSURLConnection.

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection had some activity on it, it would be okay to leave it open for a long period of time.

If you are talking about long periods of *inactivity* - that is another issue.

In such cases, I don't think it would be *productive* to increase the timeout - as the odds are, the *server* on the other end would wind-up timing out the connection.

So as this is unavoidable (or uncontrollable by you, the client) - I would advise you to close the connection and re-open when need to communicate again.

Comment: what about [Comet Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)?

Comment: It might not even be the server which times out the connection.  There's a lot more equipment between the phone and the server.  Stateful firewalls and NAT gateways will many times consider an inactive connection "dead" and remove the entry for it.

Comment: @Jesse: Very true. Just today I was ssh'd into an external machine, using port 80 to get around firewall settings in my company. When I'd leave my ssh session idle for a few minutes - it would loose connectivity. Reason being: Out company's NAT/Firewall closes out HTTP (port 80) sessions which are inactive too long.